# How to sort an array of Imperial values (inches with fractions)?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, fractions

I am using the following code to sort the values using native sort algorithm.

```
usort($this->_items, function($a, $b) { return strnatcasecmp($a['label'], $b['label']);});
```

But the issue is it is not sorting values properly for the following:

```
$array=array( '18"', '4"', '18 1/2"', '18 1/4"');
```

It should sort the values in following order

```
4"
18"
18 1/4"
18 1/2"
```

Is there any way I can get this type of sorting with PHP code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tight little solution ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f28206a6f81c424cb0d7fa0b2553057b76673c9)):

```
$array=array('18 1/2"','18"','4"','18 11/12"','18 1/4"');
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $copy[$k]=preg_match("/(\d+)\/(\d+)/",$v,$m)?$m[1]/$m[2]+(int)$v:(int)$v;
}
array_multisort($copy,SORT_NUMERIC,$array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '4"',
  1 => '18"',
  2 => '18 1/4"',
  3 => '18 1/2"',
  4 => '18 11/12"',
)
```

`foreach()` iterates `$array` and calls [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on each value to generate the `$copy` array values.  If it contains a trailing fraction, then the fraction is converted to decimal format and added to the integer, else the string value is converted to an integer.

Then `$copy` is used by [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort `$array`.  Done!

---

Years later, I'd probably use this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZKFnV))

```
$array = [
    '18 1/2"',
    '18"',
    '4"',
    '18 11/12"',
    '18 1/4"'
];

$asDecimal = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(\d+)(?: (\d+)\/(\d+))?"/',
    function ($m) {
        return $m[1] . (isset($m[3]) ? $m[2] / $m[3] : '');
    },
    $array
);

var_export($asDecimal);
echo "\n";
array_multisort($asDecimal, SORT_NUMERIC, $array);
var_export($array);
```

Comment: @p4pravin If this doesn't correctly sort all of your possible sizes, please update your question to provide a sample input where my method fails and I'll fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue today the only difference was the number format was slightly different.

5/8

1-3/4

2-13/54

54/64

and a couple hundred more in this style my regex solution was

```
preg_match_all("/(^.*?)-?(\d+)\/(\d+)/",$input,$matches)
```

the main advantage to this over the supplied answer is that the first capture group will always match the whole number and in cases where you would have to supply the previous regex with 0 5/8 or 0-5/8 you can simply let the regex leave the first capture group empty. after that its as simple as

```
$decimalConversion = $matches[2]/$matches[3]+$matches[1]
```

If you are curious about $matches[0] that will return all matches. Also whole numbers are not matched by this regex but since you really do not need to do any conversion with these as long as they remain in the array you should still be able to pull a sort correctly.

Also I pulled in array_msort from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php as an easier to read and use alternative to array_multisort

after that I used array_values($array) to reset the keys to the new sort and passed the keys back to magento as the sort_order for the option_id of the value by writing directly to the eav_attribute_option table.